# IOS : issues while uploading application from application loader

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, application-loader

developing with **xcode 7.3** and deployment target **IOS 9**. 
while uploading application from application loader, it's show this 4 error as shown in image.

**what i try**

- check all app icon and splash screen image size : it's all fine
- Check certificate : that is also fine.

it will be great if any one can help me for this

Thank you in advance 
[image: error log while uploading app]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

by some reason Images.xcassets's target MemberShip was uncheck don't know how. after check target as shown in image all work fine.

[image]